# Interpreting serial port message

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to interpret some serial port message coming from an GPS device using Python.
From what I know:
1) The message is in ascii
2) The message is continuous streaming

Therefore my code is:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM6',9600)
while True:
 ser.close()
 ser.open()
 line = ser.readline()
 print ('original code')
 print (line)
 result=line.decode(encoding='ascii',errors='strict')
 print ('decoded msg')
 print (result)
```

However, I get some very strange results:

original code

```
b'\xb5b\x02\x10\xe0\x00\'\xe4B\x01\xd7\x06\t\x00\x00\x00t\x07\xc0\x1f\x1aA\x80g*F\xc2\x8csA\xa4\xc9P\xc4\x13\x04\x19\x03\x12\xea\x86\xa1\xcc\xc16\xc1z\x19x\xab\x93asA\xde7\x16E\x0b\x07"\x00\x00\x80T7\xb1\xee&\xc1\xc6M[\xb8K\xc1sA\xec\x02\x88D\x07\x04\x16\x03\x00\x00\xf9G\x9b\xc7+A\x19\xd1\x0e\xce\x92\x12tA\xdc\x97\xcc\xc4\x03\x04\x18\x03\x00\x80`\xa9\xb3\x0b/A\x0c\x1c\x19\xa0\x1b\x0euA2\xc2\xdf\xc4\x1b\x04\x16\x03\r\xd0\x9c\x81\x03\xa7@\xc1s-\xb2\xe9{\xc3tA\xd1AdE\x01\x07"\x00\x00\xc0/"&\x150A9\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/2_Task1/test2.py", line 11, in <module>
    result=line.decode(encoding='ascii',errors='strict')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What I want to do is:
1) decode the message without losing any data to store all of them in legible format
2) know why the length of the code is different every time I run the loop

Comment: `.readline()` reads until it gets a newline. You probably want to use something like `.read(100)`.

Comment: There are some flags you can set on the serial object that might fix your problem. Try different settings for `ser.parity` and `ser.bytesize`, maybe that might help. If your system is using a parity bit, that could explain why your data looks like it's outside the ASCII range.